# How to pass a variable to .setOption

Tags: charts

I need to change the chart type to line for the last series.  The last series is a dynamic number where it depends on the user data.  May I know what is the syntax to pass the series number as the variable in the .setOption

My script as below

```
.setOption('series',{24: {type: 'line'}})
```

The number `24` is actually a dynamic number.  I need to change this to a variable to handle that. But I'm not sure what is the syntax to pass a variable to the `.setOption`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

build the series option in a variable
then pass the variable to `setOption`

```
var seriesNumber = 24;
var seriesOption = {};
seriesOption[seriesNumber] = {type: 'line'};

chart.setOption('series', seriesOption);
```

Comment: The answer did fixed my problem.  Thank you so much